# Dynamic routing in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, dynamic, routes

I'm trying to set dynamic routes for small CMS. Is there proper way how to do it? I founded somewhere this soliution, but honestly I'm not satisfied with it. CMS have other content types so define this for every model does't seem right to me.

```
$productsModel = ClassRegistry::init('Product');
$products = $productsModel->find('all');    
foreach($products as $product){
  Router::connect('/produkty/:id/'.$product['Product']['url'], array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view',$product['Product']['id']));
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do anything complex :)

In routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/produkty/*', array('controller'=>'products', 'action'=>'view'));
```

In products_controller.php:

```
function view($url = null) {
    $product = $this->Product->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Product.url' => $url)));
    ...
}
```

Comment: I just started with CakePHP so I didn't realize that functions can have other parameters no just ID. So now I have to define unique validation for url in model and it's done. Thanks!

Comment: I just bumped to one little problem. This your solution is great, but I have one content type called _mainpage_ and this one has really specific routing. URL from this type shoud be right after domain name e.g `http://cake.dev/contact`. Any help with this? Thanks

Comment: If it is just a few pages, I recommend just creating an explicit route for each of them as it is a cleaner solution: `Router::connect('/contact', array('controller'=>'mainpages', 'action'=>'view', 'contact'));`  If you have too many, you can add a catch-all at the end of routes.php to pass anything that doesn't match to your mainpages controller.  Continued in next comment...

Comment: `Router::connect('*', array('controller'=>'mainpages', 'action'=>'view'));`  There are two problems with this. You will have to add routes for all of your other controllers+actions above the catch-all.  Secondly, you will need to add a 404 error call to mainpages_controller->view() if the page is not found.

Comment: I tried `Router::connect('*', array('controller'=>'mainpages', 'action'=>'view'));` but i had problem with it. I cannor declare routes staticly, because administrator of site, can always create new one, so I used code from  my original post for now.

Answer (score 2):

Yop,

You don't need to define route for each entry in your model DB. Routes ARE dynamics. There are many ways to define routes but the easier is to pass args to action like they comes.

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/produkty/*', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view'));
```

products_controller.php

```
class ProductsController extends AppController{
    public function view($id){
         //do anything you want with your product id
    }
}
```

---

You can also use named args

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/produkty/:id/*', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view'), array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

products_controller.php

```
class ProductsController extends AppController{
    public function view(){
         //named args can be find at $this->params['named']
         $productId = $this->params['named']['id'];
    }
}
```