# Cakephp - I want to allow a user to create his own page, the url of which would be his name

Tags: php, url, cakephp, routes

I'm trying to create an app which allows a user to create an account and then create their own page.

I'd like to use a combination of the users first and and last name as the url of their page, ie mywebsite.com/john_smith

Obviously I'd need to create a controller with an apropriate action, but how do I go about making it have the url I want?

By the way, I've read through the manual a bunch of times (all the stuff about routes esp) and read loads of tutorials and a couple of the books but there's nothing I've come across that explains this exactly.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recommend create new column for example *url* in your user table.

In **users_controller.php** specifiy view function, so you can reach users page by url no by id.

```
function view($url = null) {
  if (!$url) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid product', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
  }
  $this->set('user', $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('User.url' => $url))));
}
```

In **routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'));
```

But this can lead to problems if you are using another controllers. So I'm using something like this:

```
$usersModel = ClassRegistry::init('User');
$users = $usersModel->find('all');    
foreach($users as $user){
  Router::connect('/'.$user['User']['url'], array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view',$user['User']['url']));
}
```

I dealt with similar problem, so you can check my question.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Hopefully this is what I need. One question though, if I have hundreds or even thousands of users will this not create a huge number of routing instructions? And if so does that create any problems? -- sorry if thats a newbie question

Comment: I also started with CakePHP like two weeks ago so it's hard for me to give some advices, but in my thread nobody knows better solution. This one is cleaner `Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'));` but you need  add routes for all of your other controllers and all actions too. btw if somebody answer your question properly and it help you, it's good if your set this question as solved.

Comment: Again sorry for being a newbie: I understand the router idea where you use the foreach loop, it has a rule for each user url and the rule says - if the url has /john_smith then send to users::view with john_smith as parameter. Continued next comment

Comment: But... I don't understand the Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view')); does that not say send any url to users::view? I'm a bit new to php too by the way, finding things tough

Comment: It's exactly as you wrote, that's why you need specify all other controllers and all they actions so that aplication will work. You shoud definitely check my old question it may clarify this to you.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. Thanks for your help by the way. Most kind. I've changed the answer to answered. Cheers :)

Comment: Hey s7anley, thought this thread over from the google groups for cake might be of interest to you too, http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/b65fa0809298ee57#

Answer (score 0):

Check out [dynamic routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694824/dynamic-routing-in-cakephp)